# Script properties becomes corrupt: Failed to save Project Properties for script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script properties becomes "corrupt" after a call to "PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(properties)" in my script. By "corrupt", I mean I can no longer add or edit existing properties in: "File -> Project properties -> Script properties", and when I first try I receive the error message "Failed to save Project Properties for script." I've tried deleting all properties and re-adding them, I tried deleting all browser cache, and I tried minimizing my Properties calls to ensure(?) I'm not exceeding quotas.

After this error, going to "File -> Project properties" results in in a endlessly spinning busy cursor while it tries to load the "Info" tab. Re-loading the spreadsheet allows "File -> Project properties" to properly load, but any edits made to properties in the "Script properties" tab brings back the error and spinning cursor problem.

I've narrowed down the culprit in my script but I cannot figure out why it's causing this problem. In my "onOpen()" method I am building up ~125 properties, and then I set them with one call to "setProperties()". The properties go into Script Properties okay, and they function as expected, but this programmatic setting of script properties is definitely the cause of the "Failed to save Project Properties for script." error message.

[Link to a copy of my Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zbBn2YK1J18XqpNrTu_aVBx7BlqsPErlyOpUyFGQUa4/edit?usp=sharing) containing the script causing the problem. The 3 calls causing the problem are commented with "SETPROPS", and the call to set the properties is commented with "BROKE!". This problem, or ones similar, have come up in the past but seem to be "fixed" or no longer occur.

The code sequence is as follows:

1. I clear all script properties with: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties()
2. I call three methods, each taking a "properties" argument.
3. Each of these 3 methods does nearly the same thing. They each add key/value pairs to "properties".
4. After each of the 3 methods is called, I set the properties with:

   if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(properties).length !== 0)
   {
       PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(properties);
   }

Here is one of the 3 methods that adds to the "properties" var (initialize with: var properties = {};). The other 3 methods add to the properties variable in the same manner, but operate on different data.

```
function setScriptPropertiesShipSizesForFaction(properties, factionName)
{
    var dataSheetName = factionName + "Data";
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSheetName);
    var shipValues = dataSheet.getRange('B3:D200').getValues();
    var index = 0;

    while ( (index < shipValues.length) && (shipValues[index][0] != "") )
    {
        var key = '_shipSize_' + normalize(shipValues[index][0]);
        var value = shipValues[index][2];
        properties[key] = value;
        index++;
    }
}
```

I believe I am not exceeded any Google script quota. I do not get any error messages from the call to "setProperties", and I do not see any errors in Google's Stackdriving Logging. At the bottom of this post I have a list of what I am setting in ScriptProperties. It's logging output, with syntax: key=value.

```
_shipSize_ArquitensCC=S
_shipSize_ArquitensLC=S
_shipSize_AssaultFrigateMk2A=M
_shipSize_AssaultFrigateMk2B=M
_shipSize_CR90-A=S
_shipSize_CR90-B=S
_shipSize_GR-75CombatRetrofits=S
_shipSize_GR-75MediumTransports=S
_shipSize_Gladiator1=S
_shipSize_Gladiator2=S
_shipSize_GozantiAssault=S
_shipSize_GozantiCruisers=S
_shipSize_HammerheadScout=S
_shipSize_HammerheadTorpedo=S
_shipSize_ISD1=L
_shipSize_ISD2=L
_shipSize_ISDCymoon=L
_shipSize_ISDKuat=L
_shipSize_InterdictorCombat=M
_shipSize_InterdictorSuppression=M
_shipSize_MC30cScout=S
_shipSize_MC30cTorpedo=S
_shipSize_MC75ArmoredCruiser=L
_shipSize_MC75OrdnanceCruiser=L
_shipSize_MC80AssaultCruiser=L
_shipSize_MC80BattleCruiser=L
_shipSize_MC80CommandCruiser=L
_shipSize_MC80StarCruiser=L
_shipSize_Nebulon-BEscort=S
_shipSize_Nebulon-BSupport=S
_shipSize_PeltaAssault=S
_shipSize_PeltaCommand=S
_shipSize_QuasarFire1=M
_shipSize_QuasarFire2=M
_shipSize_Raider1=S
_shipSize_Raider2=S
_shipSize_Victory1=M
_shipSize_Victory2=M
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireDEFENSIVE 2=6.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireDEFENSIVE=5.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireEXPERIMENTAL 2=8.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireEXPERIMENTAL=7.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireFLEET COMMAND=9.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireFLEET SUPPORT=10.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireION CANNONS=11.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireOFFENSIVE 2=13.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireOFFENSIVE=12.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireOFFICER=4.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireORDNANCE=14.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireSUPPORT TEAM=15.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireTITLE=3.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireTURBOLASER 2=17.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireTURBOLASER=16.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireWEAPONS TEAM 2=19.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_EmpireWEAPONS TEAM=18.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelDEFENSIVE 2=7.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelDEFENSIVE=6.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelFLEET COMMAND=8.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelFLEET SUPPORT=9.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelION CANNONS=10.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelOFFENSIVE=11.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelOFFICER 2=5.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelOFFICER=4.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelORDNANCE 2=13.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelORDNANCE=12.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelSUPPORT TEAM=14.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelTITLE=3.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelTURBOLASER 2=16.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelTURBOLASER=15.0
_upgradeKeyPrefix_RebelWEAPONS TEAM=17.0
_upgradeSize_BailOrgana=ML
_upgradeSize_DisposableCapacitors=SM
_upgradeSize_GovernorPryce=ML
_upgradeSize_HardenedBulkheads=L
_upgradeSize_StrategicAdviser=L calculatedDataSheetName=Calculated Data cellCommander=E2 colEmpirePlayerNames=1 colRebelPlayerNames=8
colShipNames=2 colSquadNames=2 colUpgradesStart=3
colVariableUpgradesEndEmpire=19 colVariableUpgradesEndRebel=17
colVariableUpgradesStartEmpire=5 colVariableUpgradesStartRebel=6
disabledBgColor=#999999 enabledBgColor=#93c47d
factionNameEmpire=Empire factionNameRebel=Rebel
indexFleetSheetsStart=3
multipleIconUpgrade_BoardingEngineers=OFFENSIVE,WEAPONS TEAM
multipleIconUpgrade_BoardingTroopers=OFFENSIVE,WEAPONS TEAM
multipleIconUpgrade_ChamSyndulla=OFFENSIVE,WEAPONS TEAM
multipleIconUpgrade_DarthVader=OFFENSIVE,WEAPONS TEAM
multipleIconUpgrade_JynErso=OFFENSIVE,WEAPONS TEAM playersPerTeam=3
rowPlayerNamesStart=7 rowShipsEnd=17 rowShipsStart=6
rowSquadNamesEnd=44 rowSquadNamesStart=21 rowUpgradeNames=5
sheetNameSystemTracking=Systems Tracking sheetNameTeamStatus=Team
Status upgradeKeyPrefix=_upgradeKeyPrefix_
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireDEFENSIVE 2=6.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireDEFENSIVE=5.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireEXPERIMENTAL 2=8.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireEXPERIMENTAL=7.0 upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireFLEET
COMMAND=9.0 upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireFLEET SUPPORT=10.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireION CANNONS=11.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireOFFENSIVE 2=13.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireOFFENSIVE=12.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireOFFICER=4.0 upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireORDNANCE=14.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireSUPPORT TEAM=15.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireTITLE=3.0 upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireTURBOLASER
2=17.0 upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireTURBOLASER=16.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireWEAPONS TEAM 2=19.0
upgradeKeyPrefixEmpireWEAPONS TEAM=18.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelDEFENSIVE 2=7.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelDEFENSIVE=6.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelFLEET
COMMAND=8.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelFLEET SUPPORT=9.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelION CANNONS=10.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelOFFENSIVE=11.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelOFFICER
2=5.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelOFFICER=4.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelORDNANCE
2=13.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelORDNANCE=12.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelSUPPORT TEAM=14.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelTITLE=3.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelTURBOLASER 2=16.0
upgradeKeyPrefixRebelTURBOLASER=15.0 upgradeKeyPrefixRebelWEAPONS
TEAM=17.0 upgradeRegex_DEFENSIVE 2=MC80\s+Assault
upgradeRegex_DEFENSIVE=Arquitens|ISD\s+(2|Kuat)|Assault\s+Frigate|CR90|MC30|MC75|MC80\s+(Assault|Command)
upgradeRegex_EXPERIMENTAL 2=Suppression
upgradeRegex_EXPERIMENTAL=Interdictor upgradeRegex_FLEET
COMMAND=Pelta|ISD\s+Cymoon upgradeRegex_FLEET SUPPORT=Gozanti|GR\-75
upgradeRegex_ION
CANNONS=CR90\-B|ISD\s+(2|Kuat|1)|Interdictor|MC75\s+Armored|MC80|Raider\s+2|Victory\s+2
upgradeRegex_OFFENSIVE 2=ISD\s+1|Quasar\s+Fire\s+1
upgradeRegex_OFFENSIVE=Gozanti|ISD|Interdictor|Quasar|Raider|Victory|Assault\s+Frigate|GR\-75|Hammerhead|MC75|MC80\s+Command|Pelta\s+Command
upgradeRegex_ORDNANCE 2=MC75\s+Ordnance
upgradeRegex_ORDNANCE=Hammerhead\s+Torpedo|Gladiator|ISD\s+Kuat|MC30|MC75|Raider\s+1|Victory\s+1|Pelta\s+Assault
upgradeRegex_SUPPORT
TEAM=Arquitens\s+CC|CR90|Gladiator|Interdictor|MC80|Pelta|Nebulon
upgradeRegex_TURBOLASER 2=ISD\s+Cymoon|MC80\s+(Star|Battle)
upgradeRegex_TURBOLASER=Arquitens|Assault\s+Frigate|CR90\-A|Hammerhead\s+Scout|ISD\s+(2|Cymoon|1)|MC30|MC75\s+Armored|MC80|Nebulon|Victory
upgradeRegex_WEAPONS TEAM 2=Quasar\s+Fire\s+2 upgradeRegex_WEAPONS
TEAM=Assault\s+Frigate|Hammerhead|Gladiator|ISD|MC30|MC75|MC80\s+(Battle|Star)|Quasar|Raider|Victory
```

Comment: If you believe setting / reading these values `onOpen` is causing issues, why on earth would you link to your document from a public website? Also note that linking offsite to your trouble document is almost never a good idea. If i see a link like that it usually means the askee doesn't know how to explain their issue, or hasn't even bothered to try and simplify the issue to figure out what is really going on.

Comment: The link is a copy of the spreadsheet for anyone who is willing to help to see the full context, if needed. I hope the post conveys the problem well enough, but if not, the full source is there. Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: Have you considered storing related properties in a single object, to reduce the number of separate properties being written and retrieved? For example, all of your `_upgradeKeyPrefix_*` properties could be stored in a single map.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm experiencing much the same problem too.  There's an older version of [this Google Apps Script](https://github.com/RobbieCoombs/Drive_Security) running and it's got around the same number of Properties.  Going via the GAS interface I can't delete any of the properties.  I've only just come across this problem so I haven't yet delved into a solution.  The property I'm storing is a token for each user for a Service Account to utilise, so I'm hoping a programmatic purge of the tokens every x days will suffice.  I'll post updates here.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was because you submitted this as an answer to this question, but it does not include potential solution to his problem (you even mention how you haven't delved into a solution). So this probably should have been posted as a comment to his question rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i couldn't save any file because an old linked library was deleted.